# How to perform filtering based on navigational properties EFCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

In my project I have a Box Entity:

```
public class Box : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public BoxSize Size { get; set; } = BoxSize.Small;
        public BoxColor Color { get; set; } = BoxColor.Black;
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Which has list of products as navigational property:

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
        public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
        public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
        public int ProductBrandId { get; set; }
        public ProductBrand ProductBrand { get; set; }
        public int? BoxId { get; set; }
        public Box Box { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

When filtering the box, I have to filter them by brands, types or categories of products inside. To filter, I use a separate object ProductParams:

```
public class ProductParams
    {
        ...
        public int? BrandId { get; set; }
        public int? TypeId { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Sort { get; set; }
        private string _search;
        public string Search
        {
            get => _search;
            set => _search = value.ToLower();
        }
    }
```

The idea of action is depicted in this code:

```
            var result = new List<Box>();
            foreach (var box in boxes)
            {
               bool isSearch = false, isType = false, isBrand = false, isCategory = false;
               foreach (var product in box.Products)
               {
                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productParams.Search))
                   {
                       if (product.Name.ToLower().Contains(productParams.Search.ToLower()))
                           isSearch = true;
                   }
                   else
                       isSearch = true;

                   if (productParams.TypeId != null)
                   {
                       if (product.ProductTypeId == productParams.TypeId)
                           isType = true;
                   }
                   else
                       isType = true;

                   if (productParams.BrandId != null)
                   {
                       if (product.ProductBrandId == productParams.BrandId)
                           isBrand = true;
                   }
                   else
                       isBrand = true;

                   if (productParams.CategoryId != null)
                   {
                       if (product.CategoryId == productParams.CategoryId)
                           isCategory = true;
                   }
                   else
                       isCategory = true;
               }
               if (isSearch && isType && isBrand && isCategory)
                   result.Add(box);
```

I would like to know whether is it possible to implement the code above as a Linq query as there is a double loop.
For example:

```
var boxes = _context.Boxes
                    .Include(b => b.Products)
                        .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductBrand)
                    .Include(b => b.Products)
                        .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductType)
                    .Include(b => b.Products)
                        .ThenInclude(p => p.Category)
                    .Where(***/// Some code I am looking for using ProductParams///***)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: It is for SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using `PredicateBuilder` from LINQKit library:

Schematically it should looks like:

```cs
var query = _context.Boxes
    .Include(b => b.Products)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductBrand)
    .Include(b => b.Products)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductType)
    .Include(b => b.Products)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Category)
    .AsQueryable();

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<Box>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productParams.Search))
    predicate = predicate.And(box => box.Products.Any(product => product.Name.ToLower().Contains(productParams.Search.ToLower())));

if (productParams.TypeId != null)
    predicate = predicate.And(box => box.Products.Any(product => product.ProductTypeId == productParams.TypeId));

if (productParams.BrandId != null)
    predicate = predicate.And(box => box.Products.Any(product => product.ProductBrandId == productParams.BrandId));

if (productParams.CategoryId != null)
    predicate = predicate.And(box => box.Products.Any(product => product.CategoryId == productParams.CategoryId));

var result = query.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Check for performance, if it is not effective, probably better to do that via GroupBy. I assume that you use EF Core 5.x:

```cs
var query = _context.Boxes
    .Include(b => b.Products)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductBrand)
    .Include(b => b.Products)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductType)
    .Include(b => b.Products)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Category)
    .AsQueryable();

var grouped = context.Products
    .Where(product => product.BoxId != null)
    .GroupBy(product => product.BoxId)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        BoxId = g.Key,
        IsSearch = productParams.Search == null || productParams.Search == '' ? true : 
            g.Count(product => product.Name.ToLower().Contains(productParams.Search.ToLower()) > 0, 
        IsType = productParams.TypeId == null ? true : 
            g.Count(product => product.ProductTypeId == productParams.TypeId) > 0, 
        IsBrand = productParams.BrandId == null ? true : 
            g.Count(product => product.ProductBrandId == productParams.BrandId) > 0,
        IsCategory = productParams.CategoryId == null ? true : ;
            g.Count(product => product.CategoryId == productParams.CategoryId) > 0
    })
    .Where(g => g.IsSearch && g.IsType && g.IsBrand && g.IsCategory)

var result = query
    .Join(grouped, box => box.Id, g => g.BoxId, (box, g) => box)
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is there any way I can generalize it? I am using GenericRepository<T> which receives ISpecification<T> as parameter to a method. ISpecification contains Include statements, Criteria(.Where()), OrderBy, and few more. Then it builds the query of that specification by taking value of fields in ISpecification, null-checking and actually building a query like query = query.Where(spec.Criteria). And I have different spec for products and boxes. Is that shitty design? If not, how can I arrange it so I can use the code you provided?

Comment: Generic repository is evil. You need such search for only several places, but dynamic implementation needs some skills and efforts.

Comment: So it is better to stick to static repositories like Product/BoxRepository? Then where is it best to implement such code that you have written? In the repository itself, right?

Comment: Or service, whatever. Yes, better to write static repository for such case. I personally can write any dynamic query, but here see just wasting of time when doing that.

Comment: Well, in my case I am building a WebApi and have following separation: Controller -> Service -> Unit of Work -> Repository. Does such layering make sense? I do not yet feel I really need Services part, because not yet much happening there.

Comment: Don't change anything, just create static repository for Box with method `Search`. I'm not good in designing boilerplate. Anyway `DbContext` is already UOW, `DbSet` is already repository.